# Android app not starting after i added admob activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, admob

I am not able to load my android app after i added the admob activity to the project. I have added an Intestitial type admob activity.

AdmobActivity layout file

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".AdmobActivity">
<!-- view for AdMob Interstitial Ad -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/app_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:text="@string/interstitial_ad_sample"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/level"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/app_title"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/start_level"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/next_level_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/next_level" />
```

Manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <!-- Include the AdActivity configChanges and theme. -->
        <activity android:name=".AdmobActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
```

AdmobActivity.java

```
package com.mtapp.quizapp;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AdmobActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    // Remove the below line after defining your own ad unit ID.
    private static final String TOAST_TEXT = "Test ads are being shown. "
            + "To show live ads, replace the ad unit ID in res/values/strings.xml with your own ad unit ID.";

    private static final int START_LEVEL = 1;
    private int mLevel;
    private Button mNextLevelButton;
    private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
    private TextView mLevelTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_admob);

        // Create the next level button, which tries to show an interstitial when clicked.
        mNextLevelButton = ((Button) findViewById(R.id.next_level_button));
        mNextLevelButton.setEnabled(false);
        mNextLevelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showInterstitial();
            }
        });

        // Create the text view to show the level number.
        mLevelTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.level);
        mLevel = START_LEVEL;

        // Create the InterstitialAd and set the adUnitId (defined in values/strings.xml).
        mInterstitialAd = newInterstitialAd();
        loadInterstitial();

        // Toasts the test ad message on the screen. Remove this after defining your own ad unit ID.
        Toast.makeText(this, TOAST_TEXT, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_admob, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private InterstitialAd newInterstitialAd() {
        InterstitialAd interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.interstitial_ad_unit_id));
        interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                mNextLevelButton.setEnabled(true);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                mNextLevelButton.setEnabled(true);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                // Proceed to the next level.
                goToNextLevel();
            }
        });
        return interstitialAd;
    }

    private void showInterstitial() {
        // Show the ad if it's ready. Otherwise toast and reload the ad.
        if (mInterstitialAd != null && mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Ad did not load", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            goToNextLevel();
        }
    }

    private void loadInterstitial() {
        // Disable the next level button and load the ad.
        mNextLevelButton.setEnabled(false);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .setRequestAgent("android_studio:ad_template").build();
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
    }

    private void goToNextLevel() {
        // Show the next level and reload the ad to prepare for the level after.
        mLevelTextView.setText("Level " + (++mLevel));
        mInterstitialAd = newInterstitialAd();
        loadInterstitial();
    }
}
```

build.gradle contains implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.2.0'

Comment: add to manifest <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="@string/app_id"/>

Comment: Include your logcat to assist clearly.

Comment: It worked when i added the above meta data with the app id i got from admob